# AWS CLI command negative condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to get the list of instances that don't have the required tags.

I can run the following to get the instances that match the following tags:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --output table  --filters 'Name=tag:bu,Values=hr' 'Name=tag:product,Values=payroll' 'Name=tag:environment,Values=development'  --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value,InstanceId,State.Name]'`

How I can get the list of instances that don't have the tags in the command above.

Thank you.

Felix

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirements? For example, are you looking for instances that don't have entries for the `bu`, `product` and `environment` tags, or for those specific values of the tags? What about an instance that has _one_ of those tags but not the others?

Comment: I want to list the instances that don't have all those 3 tags.

Comment: When you say "all those 3 tags", do you mean that it has tags for `bu`, `product` and `environment` with any values, or does it also need to have those specific values (`hr`, `payroll`, `development`) for each tag too?

Comment: These three tags should have specific tags: bu: hr, product: payroll, environment: development

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *get-resources* method from [*resourcegroupstaggingapi*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/index.html) in combination with *jq* command:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 --resource-type-filters ec2:instance | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select((contains({Tags: [{Key: "bu"}]}) or contains({Tags: [{Key: "product"}]}) or contains({Tags: [{Key: "environment"}]})) | not) | .ResourceARN'
```

This command returns the ARN of the EC2 instances which does not have none of these tags: bu, product, environment

Comment: This command doesn't return anything

Comment: If it doesn't return anything is because there are not instances that matches the filter. Try changing it with other tags to test it

Comment: No, there are 100s of instances with these 3 tags.

Comment: The command returns instances without any of those 3 tags. According to the question it is what you require